# Objective C error: Passing argument 1 of 'setStringValue:' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, system

Ok here is part of the code that is causing the error:

```
    char charlieReturn[10000];
charlieReturn[10000] = system("osascript /applications/jarvis/scripts/getTextCharlieResponce.scpt");


 self.charlieOutput.stringValue = charlieReturn;
```

The getTextCharlieResponce.scpt returns something like this: "Hi my name is charlie" and maybe sometimes it will be longer than that. The script returns it plain text. I need help FAST!

Thanks in advance! :D

Elijah

Comment: What's charlieOutput, and charlieOutput.stringValue?

The error tells you that you are trying to set stringValue to a char array, and that stringValue is not a char array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there are many problems in your code.

1. The `C` function [`system`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html) *does not* return the standard output of the script as `char*`.
2. Even with a function which returns `char*`, you can't assign it to a array of `char` as you did:

   ```
    char* str="aeiou";
    char foo[100];
    foo[100]=str;   /* doesn't work */
    foo=str;   /* doesn't work either */
   ```
3. Cocoa's string class, `NSString*`, is not a C string `char*`, although you can easily convert between the two:

   ```
    NSString* str=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"aeiou"];
   ```

If you want a string out of a call to an Apple script, you need to do the following:

1. Prepare an  [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

   ```
   NSDictionary* errorDict;
   NSAppleScript* script=[[NSAppleScript alloc] 
                           initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/script" ]
                                           error:&errorDict];
   ```
2. Execute and get a reply:

   ```
   NSAppleEventDescriptor* desc=[script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
   NSString* result=[desc stringValue];
   ```
3. Release the script:

   ```
   [script release];
   ```

Learn C & [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) and have fun!

Comment: +1 Ok, much faster and in more depth... no need to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a character array to what is presumably an NSString.  Try this instead:

```
self.charlieOutput.stringValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:charlieReturn];
```

Comment: Ok, it makes charlieOutput blank... :( Any ideas??